# Filling 4 variable in a struct type and using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I need to write a simple program that ask the user to insert 4 double type variable in a struct variable data.

```
   struct Data  
    {
      double a;
      double b;
      double c;
      double average;
    };
struct Data *ptr_name;
int i;
```

First, ask user the size:

```
 printf("Please enter the size:");
 scanf("%d", &size);
```

Then, use the malloc. (I dont know how to use it...)

something like this... `ptr_name = ()malloc();`

and then use the for loop to get the a, b, c from user.

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
 //dont know how to put the staement..
}
```

finally, print everything out, including the average.

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
     //same as above...
    }
```

That is pretty much all, I am learning struct type and malloc now, can't understand by browsing web...  help, thanks.

Comment: I highly suspect that you are supposed to be using an array rather than a struct to hold this data.  Unless you are being taught about variable length structs (which I doubt) it would make a lot more sense to ask for the size of an array than the size of a struct.

Comment: the former question is keep asking the variable and store them in a struct type till users enter 0, 0, 0 to stop the loop. Now i have to change to ask the size, which is how many time to loop and store the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `malloc` should be:

```
ptr_name = malloc (sizeof (struct Data) * size);
```

The following functions read/write instances of `struct Data` from/to the console:

```
static struct Data 
read_from_console ()
{
  struct Data d;

  d.a = 0.0f; d.b = 0.0f; d.c = 0.0f; d.average = 0.0f;
  printf ("Enter values separated by comma: (a, b, c): ");
  fflush (stdout);
  if (scanf ("%lf, %lf, %lf", &d.a, &d.b, &d.c) != 3)
    {
      printf ("Invalid input\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  else
    d.average = (double) ((d.a + d.b + d.c) / 3.0f);
  return d;
}

static void
print_to_console (struct Data* d)
{
  printf ("a=%f, b=%f, c=%f, average=%f\n", d->a, d->b, d->c, d->average);
  fflush (stdout);
}
```

You can call them from the loops inside the `main` function:

```
int
main ()
{
  struct Data *ptr_name;
  int count;
  int i;

  printf ("Please enter size: ");
  fflush (stdout);
  if (scanf ("%d", &count) != 1)
    {
      printf ("Invalid input\n");
      return 1;
    }
  ptr_name = malloc (sizeof (struct Data) * count);

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    ptr_name[i] = read_from_console ();

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    print_to_console (&ptr_name[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

A sample interaction:

```
> Please enter size: 2
> Enter values separated by comma: (a, b, c): 12.00, 12.45, 13.00
> Enter values separated by comma: (a, b, c): 5.4, 5.00, 5.1
a=12.000000, b=12.450000, c=13.000000, average=12.483333
a=5.400000, b=5.000000, c=5.100000, average=5.166667
```

Answer (score -1):

Start with

```
ptr_name = malloc( size * sizeof( *ptr_name ) );
```

See [wikipage on malloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Usage_example)

Comment: what is the difference between having a (int*) at front and have nothing at front?

Comment: () denote a type cast.  It tells the complier I know you think this is x type but I'm telling you to treat this as b

Comment: @Tim: Putting `(int *)` in front is a surefire way to demonstrate to your boss/supervisor/fellow geeks/whomever that you fail to understand how `void *` was intended to work in C.

Comment: it should be `size * sizeof(struct Data)` to allocate enough space for the struct instances.

Comment: **@Vijay Mathew:** It *could* be, but not *should* be. In fact, if you read the wikipage that I linked, you would find: "A useful idiom with malloc is shown in this example: `int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(*ptr));` That is, instead of writing a hard-wired type into the argument to malloc, one uses the sizeof operator on the content of the pointer to be allocated. This ensures that the types on the left and right of the assignment will never get out of sync when code is revised." **@Downvoter**: Why down vote? What's wrong? (BTW, since it was tagged "homework" I did not provide full answer.)